# Wordpress / JavaScript - can't get a "window.open" method to pull up an anchor tag within a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, anchor

I have a webpage in wordpress that has:

- an HTML table and
- a div that is operating like a modal (it isn't a bootstrap modal; it's all done through HTML and CSS...the wordpress template I'm using had tons of conflicts with any JS modals I tried, so I went the pure HTML and CSS route).

I'm trying to write a JS function that, upon clicking the table body, will open the modal. I'm not getting any errors when I run the code, and it's operating correctly in codepen, so I can't understand why it isn't operating correctly when I add the JS to the webpage in wordpress. I've tried searching for other instances of similar problems on Google and StackOverflow, and haven't found anything that has helped to diagnose what's causing the JS not to work properly in wordpress. Any suggestions on isolating what's causing the problem would be appreciated.

Here's the codepen that shows the HTML, CSS, and JS involved:

https://codepen.io/figment_nathan/pen/RwBXLGV

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Version 1, anchor tag (working)</h1>
<table id="table_44">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th class="column-title">Product name</th>
         <th class="column-title">Quantity</th>
         <th class="column-title">Price</th>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<div id="open-modal" class="modal-window">
  <div>
    <a href="#modal-close" title="Close" class="modal-close">close &times;</a>
    <h1>CSS Modal</h1>
    <iframe src="" name="popupiframe" height="100%" width="100%" title="Iframe Example"></iframe><p>the iframe is pulling up another page</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.modal-window {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.modal-window:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal-window > div {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 70vh;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15vh auto;
  padding: 0rem;
  background: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.modal-window header {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-close {
  color: #aaa;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.modal-close:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.modal-window h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
```

**JS (JQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tbodyco = $('#table_44').children('tbody');
    $(tbodyco).click(function () {
    window.open("#open-modal", "_self");
    });
});
```

As I mentioned above, when I click on the table body in codepen, the modal appears correctly, but when I add the JS to wordpress, nothing happens. I'm assuming there's a conflict somewhere, or that I can't run the JS function in wordpress as I've written it, but I'm at a loss on how to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I started going through the "sources" tab on DevView and found that multiple versions of JQuery were being called by various themes and plugins. I added this to my "functions.php" file for my theme in Wordpress, and the JS worked as intended:

```
    function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js', false, '3.6.3'); 
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

For anyone dealing with a similar situation in the future with JQuery and Wordpress, this might be a solution.